# MIBS and JS or jquery

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sites

I'd like to explore the possibility of using js or jquery to send snmp get requests.

Ideally I'd like pure JS so this action can be supported with google sites ( correct me if I am wrong but I don't think GS supports jquery. )

This topic may be broad but I am just looking for a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Apps Script supports jQuery in HTML Service, opposed to Javascript in a `.gs` file which is server side code.  You *can* use the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` service with advanced parameters to make a `GET` request.

[Google Documentation - jQuery - Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#jquery_and_jquery_ui)

[Google Documentation - jQuery](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#take_advantage_of_jquery)

[Google Documentation - urlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

Comment: Thanks. Good to know that GAS supports jquery. As I am new to JS ( and affiliates ) a starting point would be great ( my gpogle-fu has yielded no helpful results )

Comment: What devices to you intend to target with snmp requests? Google Apps Script runs on Google's Servers, so it your targets would need to have snmp ports open to the world. (Unless you're using some Google Apps Domain and have opened your LAN to it.)

Comment: I am in a google apps domain. I have used simpleSNMP with .net to pull the results and I am logging those results in an access database but would like to move to a native web application store the results in fusion tables.